# How do I request a scan on a Wi-Fi device using libnm?

Tags: c, linux, wifi, networkmanager

The documentation suggests I use [`nm-device-wifi-request-scan-async`](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMDeviceWifi.html#nm-device-wifi-request-scan-async), but I don't understand how to understand when it's has finished scanning. What's the correct second parameter I should pass, how is it constructed and what do I pass to [`nm-device-wifi-request-scan-finish`](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMDeviceWifi.html#nm-device-wifi-request-scan-finish)?

I've tried using [`nm-device-wifi-get-last-scan`](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/NMDeviceWifi.html#nm-device-wifi-get-last-scan) and determining whether the scan has *just* happened or the last scan was a long time ago, but it doesn't seem to update the time of the scan - i.e., after requesting the scan and printing out the time between [`nm-utils-get-timestamp-msec`](https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/libnm-nm-utils.html#nm-utils-get-timestamp-msec) and the last scan, it only increases and and decreases only if I restart the whole program, for some reason...

All I really need is to request a scan every `x` seconds and understand whether it has happened or not. The *deprecated* synchronous functions seem to have allowed this with callback functions, but I don't understand async :(

Answer (score 0):

`nm_device_wifi_request_scan_async()` starts the scan, it will take a while until the result is ready.

You will know when the result is ready when the `nm_device_wifi_get_last_scan()` timestamp gets bumped.

> it only increases and and decreases only if I restart the whole program, for some reason...

last-scan should be in `clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME)` scale. That is supposed to never decrease (unless reboot). See `man clock_gettime`.

> but I don't understand async

The sync method does not differ from the async method in this regard. They both only kick off a new scan, and when they compete, NetworkManager will be about to scan (or start shortly). The sync method is deprecated for other reasons (https://smcv.pseudorandom.co.uk/2008/11/nonblocking/).

Comment: Btw, `nm_device_wifi_get_last_scan()` is the same as the `NM_DEVICE_WIFI_LAST_SCAN` GObject property. You can `g_signal_connect(device, "notify:last-scan",...)` to get a notification when it changes.

Comment: By 'decreasing', I meant the difference between the current time and the last scan decreases. Otherwise, thanks!